# No Host Display After GPU Passthrough

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu, iommu, vfio

I am attempting to set up a GPU passthrough to use in a VM on my system. I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and have followed the instructions in the following link successfully after manually blacklisting the nouveau drivers.

https://medium.com/@calerogers/gpu-virtualization-with-kvm-qemu-63ca98a6a172

When I turn the host system on, I see the Ubuntu boot splash, but then the screen goes black and nothing is displayed. I can ssh into the system and see that the Nvidia GPU is correctly assigned to vfio-pci (as expected). I have not tested that the passthrough works on a VM yet, since I would like to get my host graphics working with the integrated Intel graphics first.

I have tried xrandr, but it says that it can't open the display. I'm expecting that there is something specific I have to do to enable the integrated graphics for the host. Any suggestions?

System:
ASRocks Z77 EXTREME4
Intel i7-4790K
Nvidia GTX 650 Ti

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem and decided not to delete the post, for anyone who this might find this helpful.

By changing the primary graphics in my BIOS from auto (which automatically chooses the Nvidia card) to integrated, everything now works exactly as expected.